# How can we check 'sf env create compute' status for Salesforce Functions?

Tags: salesforce-functions

Does anyone know how to check the status for `sf env create compute` command?

[image]

There doesn't seem to be a way to check with `sf help`.

Comment: Maybe sf env list?

Comment: run `sf env list --all` and if it is not there, it likely didn't create